# JS Fiddle & Dreamweaver

Tags: html

http://jsfiddle.net/amosrivera/AYWku/

When ever I try to implement this particular JS Fiddle into dreamweaver, the slide function on the button doesn't work at all. I have put the 'script' etc around the javascript code in the HTML document but still no avail. Any pointers with using JS fiddle?

Comment: you probably forgot yo include the jquery library

Comment: Please can you elaborate? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome to test and press F12 to see the console. If it says '$ is not a function' or so, you propably haven't got the jQuery library included. See here (http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) how to do it.

Alternatively you can use the plugin 'Firebug' in Firefox

Comment: I would appreciate, if you could mark the question as answered. Just click the gray tickmark to the left and switch it to be a green one. So I get the credits and everybody else knows, that the problem is solved

Comment: I'm puzzelled. The first time I followed the instructions, it worked perfectly - in a new HTML document. Since then, the same process hasn't allowed the script events to happen e.g. for the 'div' to appear and disappear. Should work in a non public browser? Any thoughts?

Comment: With Chrome Browser or Firebug in Firefox there comes a Network Tab. Activate it and then reload the page to see, if the jquery is loaded in the first place